# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: python, java, excel

I'am suffing this error since 2 days this shows `OutOfMemoryError` I can't understand that this error is regarding to java or python  I tried in configure java to increase the size but its failed.
This code is written in `jupiter` notebook

```
    import  jpype
    import pyspark
    from xlrd import open_workbook
    import  asposecells     
    jpype.startJVM() 
    from asposecells.api import Workbook
    workbook = Workbook(r"C:\Users\prajw\Downloads\LargeFile.xlsx")
    workbook.save(r"C:\Users\prajw\Downloads\LargeFile1.xlsb")
    jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

ERROR

```
 Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_jpype.cp39-win_amd64.pyd in com.aspose.cells.Workbook.save()

Exception: Java Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_6056\723174829.py in <module>
      6 from asposecells.api import Workbook
      7 workbook = Workbook(r"C:\Users\prajw\Downloads\LargeFile.xlsx")
----> 8 workbook.save(r"C:\Users\prajw\Downloads\LargeFile1.xlsb")
      9 jpype.shutdownJVM()

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: You have to write your problem in a proper way like this,

what is the issue, brief description of the issue, how did you get this error, A screenshot or stack trace of the error, What are you trying to achieve from this code,

Comment: The Error originates in the java virtual machine which runs out of memory. You can add startup parameters to increase the memory that the JVM is allowed to allocate (`-Xmx`), but I am not familiar with how to squeeze this into python.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change memory settings as suggested in the doc [how-to-fix-the-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-while-loading-large-spreadsheets](https://docs.aspose.com/cells/java/how-to-fix-the-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-while-loading-large-spreadsheets/)
Also there is a optimized mode
[how-to-fix-the-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-while-loading-large-spreadsheets](https://docs.aspose.com/cells/net/optimizing-memory-usage-while-working-with-big-files-having-large-datasets/)

Or else, you can choose other alternatives. [EasyExcel](https://pypi.org/project/EasyExcel/), for example, supports big excel file reading very well

Comment: there is a optimized mode https://docs.aspose.com/cells/net/optimizing-memory-usage-while-working-with-big-files-having-large-datasets/